# How to check whether string is present in array with lodash js?

Tags: javascript, lodash

My snippet looks something like this:

```
let go = "hello";

let col =["12","hello","14","15"];

let f = _.some(col,go);
```

I want to check whether the go value is present in col TRUE/FALSE.
When I run this I get , f=false? How can I fix this or how to check the presence of a string in an array of strings (with lodash)?

Answer (score 29, accepted):

Should work

```
let go = "hello";

let col =["12","hello","14","15"];

let f = _.includes(col,go);
```

https://lodash.com/docs#includes

Answer (score 4):

With only javascript you can use `indexOf`. If it is present it will return the index of the element else -1

```js
let go = "12";
let col = ["12", "hello", "14", "15"];
var isElemPresent = (col.indexOf(go) !== -1) ? true : false
console.log(isElemPresent)
```

Comment: `indexOf` will only return `1` for "hello". If you change `go` to anything else, this will return `false`. You should ideally use `!== -1`. You also need to watch out for type comparisons; `indexOf` performs a type-safe comparison so `col.indexOf('12')` will return `0` whereas `col.indexOf(12)` will return `-1`

Comment: The question is about lodash

Comment: not actually addressing the question properly since it's literally asking for lodash

Comment: user want to know the solution with lodash. He is using lodash means he is using it for a reason.

Comment: @A.Lau the question is also tagged with javascript. Also nothing stop you from using javascript if you are using loadash. Check loadash library how inlcude function is implemented.

Comment: @Phil if he implements all the functionality of library himself, what is the point using library?

Comment: Though it is downvoted I will still keep this answer.It will be unfair if I delete it. I know it is downvoted because of subjected opinion

Comment: Well obviously. All javascript libraries are implemented using, surprise, Javascript. If someone's asking for a particular function jQuery, you shouldn't go and rewrite that functionality in Javascript now should you? You also tag anything related to Javascript, with Javascript to increase the likelihood of someone knowing the answer of finding it.

Comment: I will rather focus on answering some other question instead of clarifying. Thank you

Comment: @brk it's only downvoted because of `=== 1`. This will return `false` for `'12'`, `'14'` and `'15'`

Comment: @Phil I agree with type comparison but I also validated this point _If you change go to anything else, this will return false_ & I see it is returning -1.
https://jsfiddle.net/4u5g1pz9/

Comment: `col.indexOf('12')` returns `0` which means it certainly is **present**. If `col` contains `"hello"` at position #3, this will return `false` even though `"hello"` is certainly **present**. Naming your variable `isPresent` does not fit with what your code is doing. If you want it to be completely accurate, you should name it `isHelloPresentAtExactlyTheSecondIndex`

Comment: Much better. The `? true : false` is totally redundant though

Answer (score 0):

It seems that You misunderstood what the last arguments of `_.some` is. You can't use it as a value for equality test, but You need to make one yourself like this:

`let f = _.some(col, function(go) {return go === "hello"});`

And here is working [Fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/zbt2npsh/44/) for You.

Or alternatively you can use es6 magic and call includes directly from your array like this

```js
let go = "hello";

let col =["12","hello","14","15"];

alert(col.includes(go))
```

Comment: this also searches by substring:                                                                             let f = _.some(col, function(go) { return go.toLowerCase().indexOf("he".toLowerCase()) });